# Access denied attempting to open a file on a shared folder

Tags: c#, unix, exception, file-io

I'm working on an application which has an input folder to receive some files to process. Unfortunately, our costumer has choosen UNIX as his operational system to run his main software, and he has the shared folder which we can get the content through network. His main software is quite strange to write files: firstly, it creates the file and then writes the content inside the file. The application I'm working on catchs the file at the moment it's put inside the folder and process the file. In this case, we have a "fight" accessing the file, because the main software is writing the content while my application is trying to open only to see whether it's being used by another process. Every time I try to open the file, an exception is thrown, but my catch statement doesn't catch the exception as it was to be.

The folowing code is used when I'm trying to open the file to see whether it's being used by another process:

```
public static void IsOpen(string file)
{
    bool isOpen = true;

    while (isOpen)
    {
        try
        {
            using (File.Open(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
            {
                isOpen = false;
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException exp)
        {
            throw new Exception(exp.Message);
        }
        catch (DirectoryNotFoundException exp)
        {
            throw new Exception(exp.Message);
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            isOpen = true;
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    }
}
```

It looks like `File.Open` is throwing an exeception and handling it inside the method. I have put some logs on the catchs statements to see if it's working, I've also written only `catch (Exception)`, but it's not working either.

When my application tries to open the file, which is being used by another process, it's written this message on Event Viewer: `Access to the path '<path here>' is denied`, and also this error log:

```
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath)
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
at Utilities.IsOpen(String strFile)
```

I think it's throwing an `UnauthorizedAccessException`, but my application is a Windows Service, and when the service is restarted it works properly, due to the content is already written inside the file itself.

Any ideas?
Thank you.

Comment: You need to be able to cope with this situation. You will indeed be getting an UnauthorizedAccessException. You need to implement something like a retry with timeout for that situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be able to cope with this situation. You will indeed be getting an UnauthorizedAccessException.

You need to implement something like a retry with timeout for that situation.

Comment: By any chance you have a piece of code, cause I didn't understand your point.

Comment: @GuilhermeOliveira If you get access denied, wait 5 seconds and try again. If you try again too many times, then give up.

Comment: Yes, I've already tried it, and even so it didn't work. I put the catch statement to get the `UnauthorizedAccessException` with an Event Viewer log to write to check if it happen, but unfortunately it didn't, and now I don't know what to do.

Comment: Actually, I was updating the dlls on the costumer, but I made I ruge mistake rebuilding the wrong dll. When I realized I was wrong, I put the catch statement for `UnauthorizedAccessException` and it worked pretty fine. Anyway, thank you for your help.